# CoreData Relationship - Update object in relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

Hi I have a Core Data Model that has a one to many relationship between customer and job codes.

I update the existing job codes when the user syncs data. At some point it seems that something has gone wrong with the relationship on a users device. The error is `"coredata could not fulfil a fault for ....."`

I have forced this error into our test system by deleting a customer but not the job code. the job code is still pointing to a customer that does not exist.

I know this is obviously bad, and am not 100% sure how the user has got to this situation, but it anyway.

This error is being thrown when I am trying add a valid customer to the job code object - ie

```
//get a valid customer object into a variable called aCust
NSLog(%@"%@",aCust);
aJobCode.customerForJobCode=aCust;
```

the error is thrown when setting on this line:

```
aJobCode.customerForJobCode=aCust;
```

The `aCust` object is perfectly fine and displays the correct description and relationships in the `NSLog`.

I understand that the object `ajobCode` is pointing to a customer that does not exist, but how can I now update it to a valid customer object? trying to assign a new customer object to it makes it throw the error, but is referring to the old object, that I want to replace.

trying `[aJobCode setCustomerForObject:aCust];` also throws the error. I know the relationship is broken, how can assign it a new customer object?

the stack trace is as below:

```
014-09-10 13:39:48.488 mavis[2548:1303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xd000000000380002 <x-coredata://016A347F-3FE5-4FD0-9BDE-76A8FFA8C8B4/Customer/p14>''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001032b8495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010204199e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreData                            0x000000010066c7e3 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1075
    3   CoreData                            0x000000010066bffb _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 235
    4   CoreData                            0x0000000100699a7e -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _excludeObject:fromPropertyWithKey:andIndex:] + 142
    5   CoreData                            0x0000000100692797 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 263
    6   CoreData                            0x000000010069221b -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 571
    7   Foundation                          0x0000000101a07ea2 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 375
    8   Foundation                          0x0000000101a096f0 NSKeyValueDidChange + 467
    9   Foundation                          0x00000001019cc79c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 118
    10  CoreData                            0x0000000100679fac _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeyIndex + 108
    11  CoreData                            0x00000001006794bd _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 237
    12  mavis                               0x000000010001911b -[jobsJSONSyncVC addNewJobCodes:] + 1387
    13  mavis                               0x000000010000c3f8 -[jobsJSONSyncVC getJSONSettings] + 1656
    14  mavis                               0x000000010000bca6 __38-[jobsJSONSyncVC reachabilityChanged:]_block_invoke + 182
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106bea851 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106bfd72d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106bedb27 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 380
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106bedd12 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000106f4aef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000106f4dfb9 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type _NSCoreDataException
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide the full error/exception trace?

Comment: hi, i've added it to the original post, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is typically thrown when the object you are referencing has been removed from the persistent store. An example that could generate this is when you have a reference to an object i.e. through a tableView, etc. and you delete the object then try to reference it's properties or relationships. A more obscure case is that your cache has become corrupted and you need to purge that. If you share code perhaps we can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: hi, I understand that its throwing it because it's trying to access the properties of an invalid relationship, but i'm not sure why the relationship became invalid in the live system. in my dev system I deliberately deleted only the customer object leaving the callStatus object referening the deleted customer, but this is not something that can be done in the live system.

i'd happily share the code, but i'm not sure which bits are relevant really. the code that add data to the object, or references it?

Comment: interestingly I am using adhoc  distribution for testing. I reinstalled the app over the air, and while the data remained in place (as expected as there were no data model changes) and there were no code changes, the error has exception has stopped being thrown. So without changing the data OR the code, the error has stopped. Does this indicate a caching problem? I can recreate the issue in dev. how do you force a cache refresh?

Comment: See this : http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/delete-the-nsfetchedresultscontroller-cache-before-changing-the-nspredicate and this: http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2012/03/core-data-image-caching/